# Excel conditional formatting when red colored text found in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors, conditional-formatting

I have a weird one for Excel and I'm hoping it can do it.

I have customers with many columns of data. Depending on what's found, we have conditional formatting to note anything out of the ordinary/important in each column. What I'd like to do is change the value under the "Customer" column if *any* of the cells in that row contain red text. This would be to indicate there are items further in the sheet that need to be reviewed.

A draft example would look like the following, where the top table shows where I'm at and the table below it shows where I want to get to via conditional formatting.

(if row contains any cells with red text, change the first cell of the row to red text)

[image]

Any idea how I could accomplish such a feat?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Change the conditions that colour the text red in columns `C` and `C` so that text in column `A` is also changed

Comment: My goal is to not take the focus off of the actual issue items. If the entire row is red with the amount of columns we have, then it will be difficult to hunt down where they need to look. Thank you though... good suggestion in general.

Comment: You can conditionally format multiple cells with a single condition. This would be easier if we had a better idea of your current setup (i.e. a sample condition)

Comment: Using the screenshot, let's say I have a conditional rule on the C column. Right now, it has a simple rule of "Specific Text of "broken", which will highly just that cell.

I have another column with integers. So on that column, if the cell value doesn't = 0.012, change the color of that value to red.

Another column further down, I compare 2 columns (X and Y). If X is "TRUE" and Y doesn't equal .5, then set them both to red. The formula for that condition looks like:  =AND(COUNTIF($X2,"TRUE")=1,$Y2<>0.5).

Are you saying just add the A column to the selection for that rule?

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/867092/apply-conditional-formatting-to-multiple-rows) may be of use

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad... All I really needed to do was add the first column to the selection (not sure why that didn't click for me). Thanks for guiding me to the right solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on guidance from @cybernetic.nomad, I just needed to add the Customer column when I setup the other rules for the individual columns. E.g. Select column A and C, even though your condition is only about C.